# How to enable @EnableSpringDataWebSupport with XML configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm using `Spring 5.0.2.RELEASE` and the following dependency for `Spring Data`:

```
    <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

In DispatcherServlet.xml create:

```
<bean id="mvcConversionService"
        class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration">
        <constructor-arg ref="mvcConversionService" />
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.data.web.config.QuerydslWebConfiguration" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven
        conversion-service="mvcConversionService">
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <ref bean="sortResolver" />
            <ref bean="pageableResolver" />
            <ref bean="querydslPredicateArgumentResolver" />
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

But, again have the message is:

```
No constructor with 1 argument defined in class 'org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration'
```

Who can show me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

By seeing error looks like you may have configured `SpringDataWebConfiguration` incorrectly.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration" />
```

Refer this [Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/)